# how to know if a column is auto-increment in mysql

Tags: .net, ado.net, mysql-connector, information-schema

I want to generate insert sql statement according to the tables in database, so write some code to do this, the DataProvider is MySQL Connector/Net.

```
MysqlConnection conn = new MysqlConnection("...");
DataTable dt = conn.GetSchema("Tables");

//foreach table

DataTable dt = conn.GetSchema("Columns",column_res);

//generate prepared statement sql by the columns.
```

When there is auto_increment column in table, the code can't work and I must edit it manually. Does anyone has any idea about how to know a column is auto_increment? So I can get all the sql needed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For the MySql Connector/Net,there is a "EXTRA" column in the dt of the step.

```
DataTable dt = conn.GetSchema("Columns",column_res);
```

if the column is auto_increment, the value of dt.Rows[i]["EXTRA"] is "auto increment".